# PHP скрипт для проверки и выполнения процесса

Tags: php

ОС Debian 7.

Как проверить, есть ли процесс в системе?
Если процесса нет, то запустить процесс.

Я сам с PHP не знаком, прошу вашей помощи. Путь к файлу XXX

Дополнение:

Есть клиент и удаленная машина(VDS).
Программа-клиент должна отправить машине команду о запуске файла, предварительно проверив не выполняется ли уже такой процесс

Comment: Вы уверены, что целесообразно делать это средствами php?

Comment: Ну не SSH же использовать ради одной команды? Что вы можете предложить?

Comment: Ааа, я наверно должен дополнить - забыл. Есть программа-клиент и сервер, дак вот клиент должен сделать запрос на сервер и запустить процесс.

Comment: http://supervisord.org/  ;)

Comment: Мне нужен просто PHP-скрипт, который будет лежать на машине, который нужно вызвать из клиента. С вызовом скриптов из клиента проблем нет. Есть проблема с написание PHP-скрипта

Answer (score 0):

Запустить скрипт из консоли

```
exec('php cli.php', $m);
```

Получить идентификатор процесса (проверьте на уникальность)

```
$pid = getmypid();
```

Посмотреть список всех процессов с pid из php (не все команды консоли работают)

```
exec('ps aux', $m);
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($m); echo '</pre>';
```

И ответ на ваш вопрос: как запустить с присвоением имени что бы потом контролировать:

```
$pid = getmypid();
$title = "my_php_s";

if (!cli_set_process_title($title)) {
    echo "Unable to set process title for PID $pid...\n";
    exit(1);
} else {
    echo "The process title '$title' for PID $pid has been set for your process!\n";
    sleep(5);
}
```

Но конкретно этот код только из консоли сработает а вам надо что бы он команду удалённого сервера по http принимал как API